# python pandas sort within group and apply function

Tags: python, r, pandas, apply

Let's say that I have the iris data set. Is there a way to succinctly perform the below operations in pandas?

1. Group by target
2. Within each group, arrange the data in descending order by "sepal length (cm)"
3. Within each group, assign 1 to the top 5 rows and 0 to the rest?

For those knowing R, I just want to replicate the following code (yes, it was a workaround there):

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>%
  mutate(size_tag = 1,
         size_tag = cumsum(size_tag),
         size_tag = ifelse(size_tag <= 5, 1, 0))
```

So far I have:

```
from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])

def fn(group, col_nm):
    group[col_nm] = 1
    group[col_nm] = np.cumsum(group[col_nm])
    group[col_nm] = np.where(group[col_nm] <= 5, 1, 0)
return group

iris['size_tag'] = np.NaN
iris.groupby('target').apply( pd.DataFrame.sort_values, 'sepal length (cm)' ).apply( fn, args = (['size_tag']))
```

The result I get is an extra row appended to the DataFrame...

I am just beginning using pandas and Python, so any remarks (e.g. coding style-related) are welcome.

Comment: rpl, do you know about the feather package? you can grab a data.frame and the [feather package](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/),it is a tool for improving interoperability between Python, R, it transforms your data.frame into a format that can be exchanged from R to Python and viceversa.

Comment: Yes, I do. However, I considered it weird to export iris from R and import it into Python using feather, especially that it is available in sklearn. I guess I would have then received a comment "Do you know that iris is available in sklearn?"  :-) . This will make some sense, though, if I run into the wall in Python... as a last resort. But I strongly believe that pandas is powerful enough :-). Since this is a bit of an off-top - there is a ggplot module for Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the series of ones and zeros

```
iris.sort_values(
    'sepal length (cm)', ascending=False
).groupby('target').cumcount().__floordiv__(5).eq(0).astype(np.uint8)
```

---

More readable

```
s = iris.sort_values('sepal length (cm)', ascending=False)
c = s.groupby('target').cumcount()
((c // 5) == 0).astype(np.uint8)
```

---

Produce a copy with new column

```
s = iris.sort_values('sepal length (cm)', ascending=False)
c = s.groupby('target').cumcount()
top5 = ((c // 5) == 0).astype(np.uint8)
iris.assign(size_tag=top5)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! No wonder I couldn't figure it out! Am I correct that one simply has to sort before grouping? Do you know why the code I wrote was wrong? I'd like to understand my mistake (and I have no idea why it behaved this way).

Comment: This is one way to do it.  Sorting, enabled me to know the first five are the top ones.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your R dataframe and I think this does the same thing:

```
iris = iris.sort_values(['target', 'sepal length (cm)'], ascending=False)
iris['size_tag'] = iris.index.isin(iris.groupby('target').head(5).index)*1
```

We first sort the values by the species and then by sepal length within each species group. Then we add the labels on the top 5 for each group.

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, you don't need that `cumsum()` thing to calculate row numbers. The `row_number()` function does it for you:

```
r$> iris %>% 
      group_by(Species) %>% 
      arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
      mutate(size_tag = if_else(row_number() <= 5, 1, 0))  
# A tibble: 150 x 6
# Groups:   Species [3]
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   size_tag
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>        <dbl>
 1          7.9         3.8          6.4         2   virginica        1
 2          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica        1
 3          7.7         2.6          6.9         2.3 virginica        1
 4          7.7         2.8          6.7         2   virginica        1
 5          7.7         3            6.1         2.3 virginica        1
 6          7.6         3            6.6         2.1 virginica        0
 7          7.4         2.8          6.1         1.9 virginica        0
 8          7.3         2.9          6.3         1.8 virginica        0
 9          7.2         3.6          6.1         2.5 virginica        0
10          7.2         3.2          6           1.8 virginica        0
# … with 140 more rows
```

Now we have the ability to do it in the same way in python with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, group_by, arrange, desc, mutate, row_number, if_else
>>> from datar.datasets import iris
>>> 
>>> iris >> \
...   group_by(f.Species) >> \
...   arrange(desc(f.Sepal_Length)) >> \
...   mutate(size_tag = if_else(row_number() <= 5, 1, 0))
     Sepal_Length  Sepal_Width  Petal_Length  Petal_Width    Species  size_tag
        <float64>    <float64>     <float64>    <float64>   <object>   <int64>
0             7.9          3.8           6.4          2.0  virginica         1
1             7.7          2.8           6.7          2.0  virginica         1
2             7.7          3.8           6.7          2.2  virginica         1
3             7.7          2.6           6.9          2.3  virginica         1
..            ...          ...           ...          ...        ...       ...
4             7.7          3.0           6.1          2.3  virginica         1
145           4.5          2.3           1.3          0.3     setosa         0
146           4.4          2.9           1.4          0.2     setosa         0
147           4.4          3.0           1.3          0.2     setosa         0
148           4.4          3.2           1.3          0.2     setosa         0
149           4.3          3.0           1.1          0.1     setosa         0

[Groups: Species (n=3)]
[150 rows x 6 columns]
```

I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.